# Initializing static member of a template class with both string and int(like) types

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, templates, static-members

I am trying to implement a monitor class to deal with multithreading. I must use Visual Studio 2010, so no c++11 for me. I could simply do this by creating global variables, one for each type of value I would be reading/writing across threads and use a mutex for every single one, which would be simples but way more tedious.

So I wanted to take my time and implement the monitor concept in a Class.
The job is "done" to some extent, since the data type is either float or int, but I wanted to go further and implement the monitor class to support both C standard types and c++ classes, such as strings.

My approach is to make static members work as shared memory across threads, so that the only thing I would have to do is instantiate the class in both threads and I would have the IPC properly setup.

Thing is... I have to initialize the static member and I can't get it to work because string and int-ish types (int, float etc...) are not initialized the same way.

here is what I tried to do:

```
template<class T>
class Monitor : protected Mutex {
public:
    Monitor(bool Verbose);
    ~Monitor();
    T read(DWORD wait_time=INFINITE);
    void write(T value, DWORD wait_time=INFINITE);
    //friend void operator= (Monitor& m1, Monitor& m2);
private:
    static T container;
};

template<class T>
T Monitor<T>::container = (typeid(T) == typeid(string) ? "" : 0);
```

which works alright If I only have either `Monitor<string> pMonitor2(VERB_ON);` or `Monitor<int> pMonitor1(VERB_ON);` declared. Declaring both throws me `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'int'`.

Also, what would be the best approach to implement this kind of Interprocess Communication concept in classes?

Full code so far:

monitor.cpp:

```
#include "monitor.h"

using namespace std;

HANDLE Mutex::hMutex = nullptr;
unsigned int Mutex::counter = 0;

Mutex::Mutex(bool V) {
    Verbose = V;
    if(hMutex == nullptr) {
        if(Verbose) cout << "Creating mutex\n";
        hMutex = CreateMutex(
            NULL,
            FALSE, 
            (LPCWSTR) "CONTMUTEX");
            counter++;
    }
    else{
        if(Verbose) cout <<"Mutex already created\n";
        counter++;
    }
}

Mutex::~Mutex() {
    counter--;
    if(counter == 0) {
        if(Verbose) cout << "Destroying mutex\n";
        CloseHandle(hMutex);
    }
    else {
        if(Verbose) cout << "Awaiting closure of all instances of Mutex\n";
    }
}

/*void operator= (Monitor& m1, Monitor& m2) {
    m1.write(m2.read());
}*/
```

monitor.h:

```
#ifndef MONITOR_INC
#define MONITOR_INC

//#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum verb{VERB_OFF, VERB_ON};

class Mutex {
public:
    Mutex(bool Verbose);
    ~Mutex();
protected:
    bool Verbose;
    static HANDLE hMutex;
    static unsigned int counter;
};

template<class T>
class Monitor : protected Mutex {
public:
    Monitor(bool Verbose);
    ~Monitor();
    T read(DWORD wait_time=INFINITE);
    void write(T value, DWORD wait_time=INFINITE);
    //friend void operator= (Monitor& m1, Monitor& m2);
private:
    static T container;
};

template<class T>
T Monitor<T>::container = (typeid(T) == typeid(string) ? "" : 0);

template<class T>
Monitor<T>::Monitor(bool Verbose) : Mutex(Verbose) {
    if(Verbose) cout << "Monitor Constructor\n";
}

template<class T>
Monitor<T>::~Monitor() {
    if(Verbose) cout << "Monitor Destructor\n";
}

template<class T>
T Monitor<T>::read(DWORD wait_time) {
    T ret_val;
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, wait_time);
    ret_val = container;
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    return ret_val;
}

template<class T>
void Monitor<T>::write(T value, DWORD wait_time) {
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, wait_time);
    container = value;
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
}

//void operator= (Monitor& m1, Monitor& m2);
#endif
```

main.cpp for testing:

```
#include "monitor.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    Mutex pMutex1(VERB_ON);
    Mutex pMutex2(VERB_ON);
    Mutex pMutex3(VERB_ON);

    Monitor<int> pMonitor1(VERB_ON);
    cout << pMonitor1.read() << "\n";
    pMonitor1.write(20);
    cout << pMonitor1.read() << "\n";

    Monitor<string> pMonitor2(VERB_ON);
    cout << pMonitor2.read() << "\n";
    pMonitor2.write("TURN DOWN FOR WHAT");
    cout << pMonitor2.read() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I must apologize beforehand for any bad practice. It has been like 8 months since I last coded in C++ and I am taking this opportunity to take some of the dust off my C++ coding skills.

---

### EDIT1

`T Monitor<T>::container = ( (typeid(T) == typeid(string)) ? "" : 0);` doesn't actually work for int, only string, for some reason.

Comment: I personally wouldn't try and initialize the container to a constant value of 0. You could make the constructor take an optional initial value. If you are set on initializing, you would want to test the type at compile time and not runtime. Template specialization is probably what you want to look at.

Comment: For your edit, it works for `std::string` as both are convertible to `const char*` (`0` is `nullptr`) which is a valid argument to construct a `std::string` but not for `int`.

Comment: +Phil Williams, why shouldn't I initialize to a constant value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use specialization:

```
template<class T> // general case
T Monitor<T>::container = 0;

template<>
std::string Monitor<std::string>::container = "";
```

or as you use default value

```
template<class T>
T Monitor<T>::container = T();
```

Comment: `T Monitor<T>::container = T();` works well for all the types I need. Can you tell me how good is my approach to this problem? I feel like there is a safer, faster way of doing this.